# Joomla Language Switcher : not displaying flags

Tags: joomla

I'm using joomla 3.4.1 and I'm having a problem displaying flags in my language switcher. All I see is the text for the languages.

Here are some screens:
[image: My language switcher]
[image]

Does anyone know what could be wrong ?

Comment: StackOverflow is about **development** questions. For **Joomla** related questions which are not about development, use http://joomla.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using default Joomla's Language Switcher Module, then check configuration of this module - there is information:

> If Use Dropdown is set to 'Yes', the display options below will be
>   ignored

One of the options below is: "Use Image Flags", so you can't use image flags and dropdown in the same time.

You can override \modules\mod_languages\tmpl\default.php file in your template or use different module to have both: dropdown and image flags.

Comment: Oh thanks, it was indeed the Dropdown menu set to "Yes". And i used another module to have them both.

Thanks again !